# Installing gems - what does "INFO: `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed" mean

Tags: ruby, rubygems

When I install a new gem, I see this message:

"INFO:  `gem install -y` is now default and will be removed"

What does it mean?  My quick Google search didn't turn up anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-y` option tells `gem` to install dependencies when installing the named gem. This is now the default action, so you don't need to worry about specifying the `-y` option any more. Eventually, the developers of `gem` will remove the option `-y`.

So in short, just use `gem install` instead, and ignore the `-y`.

Answer (score 0):

It means that RubyGems will automatically install any required dependent gems.

- http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page33